# IMAP to ODBC converter (i.e. IMAP to SQL)

Tags: sql, imap, converters

Please excuse me if this question has been directly asked.

I'm looking for the easiest and most robust way to get mail from our mail server (We use Kerio Connect so could use either IMAP or POP) to a database server (either MYSQL or MSSQL).

The solution will sit in a virtual server, either Ubuntu or Windows (2003 or 2008)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we used a very simple solution: a Windows Xp VM running Outlook with some VBA coding. Works well.